# Creating a form with Elm

Tags: frp, elm

I would like to create a form in Elm that takes 4 required inputs:

- 3 floating point values
- 1 input which can take the values of "long" or "short" (presumably) this would be a drop-down

When the values are entered, a computation occurs that yields a single line of output based on these values.

I have this working as a command-line Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from __future__ import print_function

# core
import logging

# pypi
import argh

# local

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(lineno)s %(message)s',
    level=logging.WARN
)

def main(direction, entry, swing, atr):

    entry = float(entry)
    swing = float(swing)
    atr   = float(atr)

    if direction == 'long':
        sl = swing - atr
        tp = entry + (2 * atr)
    elif direction == 'short':
        sl = swing + atr
        tp = entry - (2 * atr)

    print("For {0} on an entry of {1}, SL={2} and TP={3}".format(
        direction, entry, sl, tp))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argh.dispatch_command(main)
```

but want to use Elm to create a web UI for it.

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an ideal first introduction to Elm, since it takes you through a few of Elm's more difficult areas: mailboxes and the Graphics.Input library. There is also not an easy-to-deploy number input, so I've only implemented the dropdown; you'd use [Graphics.Input.Field](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Graphics-Input-Field) (which can get particularly dicey).

A mailbox is basically a signal that the dropdown input can send a message to. I've chosen for that message to be a function, specifically, how to produce a new state from the old one. We define state to be a record type (like a Python named tuple), so saving the direction involves storing the new direction in the record.

The text is rendered using a convenience function that makes it `monospace`. There's a whole [text library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Text) you can use, but Elm 0.15 does not have string interpolation, so you're stuck with the quite ugly appends.

Finally, there's not much on an Elm community on SO, but you're welcome to join the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elm-discuss) where questions like this are welcomed. That being said, you really should try to dive into Elm and learn the basics so you can ask a more specific question. This is true of almost any language, library or framework - you have to do some basic exercises before you can write "useful" code.

```
import Graphics.Input as Input
import Graphics.Element as Element exposing (Element)

mailbox = Signal.mailbox identity

type Direction = Short | Long
type alias State = {entry : Float, swing : Float, atr : Float, dir : Direction}

initialState : State
initialState = State 0 0 0 Short

dropdown : Element
dropdown =
    Input.dropDown
    (\dir -> Signal.message mailbox.address (\state -> {state| dir <- dir}))
    [("Short", Short), ("Long", Long)]

state : Signal State
state = Signal.foldp (<|) initialState mailbox.signal

render : State -> Element
render state =
    dropdown `Element.above`
    Element.show ("For "++(toString state.dir)++" on an entry of "++(toString state.entry) ++
                  ", SL="++(toString (sl state))++" and TP="++(toString (tp state)))

main = Signal.map render state

-- the good news: these are separate, pure functions
sl {entry, swing, atr, dir} =
    case dir of
        Long -> swing - atr
        Short -> swing + atr

tp {entry, swing, atr, dir} =
    case dir of
        Long -> entry + (2*atr)
        Short -> entry - (2*atr)
```

Update: I wrote [an essay](https://gist.github.com/mgold/461dbf37d4d34767e5da) on mailboxes and how to use them.